# does sublime text support theme inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, themes, sublimetext, dry

Let's say I need make only a small change in colors on a given theme, do I must copy all the old theme settings for such a small change or could I put a directive to get the rest of the definitions from given file like "Monokai.tmTheme" ?

Comment: No idea, but I usually just overwrite the old stuff.

Comment: I do not believe this (inheritance) is possible. But if you copy the 'Monokai.tmTheme' (to use your example) into your `User` folder and then make the small change you want and then the version in your personal version will overwrite the original. In effect getting what you want for the same amount of work. All you lose is any updates to the default 'Monokai.tmTheme' not being applied automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, unlike language definitions, which can be imported into other language defs, there is no method of inheritance for color schemes, as they lack any kind of `import` directive. As was suggested in the comments, the best way to tweak a `.tmTheme` file is just to copy it to your `Packages/User` directory, then edit it to make any changes you need. If you plan on making major changes, instead of messing around with editing XML files, I highly recommend using @facelessuser's [`ColorSchemeEditor`](https://github.com/facelessuser/ColorSchemeEditor) plugin. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/facelessuser/ColorSchemeEditor/issues/11) for installation instructions (make sure you read the whole thing, as building from scratch is now not required).